# Parse Migartion + "No reachable Server" + Self Hosted Server

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, cloud, database-migration

I am trying to migrate my app from parse to self hosted server.

But unable to migrate database when inserting mongodb database URI and start migration it shows :"No Reachable Server"

I am using mongoDb URI as follows:
mongodb://user:password@IP-address:27017/parse

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: I think it should be https://NAME_OF_YOUR_HEROKU_APP.herokuapp.com/parse

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply Henry Brown:)

I am using a self hosted DB and I have fixed this issue by changing port from mongob.conf file.